# FileMerge: This file type cannot be merged

Tags: macos, merge, filemerge

FileMerge.app fails with an odd message:

> This file type cannot be merged.

when I try to save successfully merged text files, which definitely *can* be merged.

(I invoke FileMerge from `git` using `opendiff` tool on OS X 10.6.3, but problem happens even when I select files to merge manually)

Why is it happening? How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Those are PHP files, containing ASCII only. Temp filenames end in `.php`. OS X associates them with TextMate and is able to show them in QuickLook.